# Sending complex type in ksoap request to Wcf web service

Tags: android, wcf, android-ksoap2

I am trying to connect to a Wcf web serice from android client.My client is working fine with simple data types but when i am trying to call with complex data it is giving issues.
I have done this:

```
 Credentials credentials=new Credentials();
  credentials.Username="xyz";
  credentials.Password="123";
  PropertyInfo info=new PropertyInfo();
  info.setName("credentials"); 
  info.setValue(credentials);               
  info.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
  info.setType(new Credentials().getClass());
  request.addProperty(info);


                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
                            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


                    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    Object response=null;
                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    response = envelope.getResponse();
```

Here whenever i send Credentials without doing the info.setValue(credentials) i am able to send the request to the server but the username and password field blank.
In case i add this info.setValue(credentials) i get eserilization error. I have wasted some 2-3 days on this please help.

Comment: are you getting response as Json string or in soap format?If you get response as Json string then we can hard code the request.

Comment: no i am sending the request as well as receiving the request in soap format..

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my question.I noticed the request generated in java and android client.

**Java client**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body><ns4:myfunction xmlns:ns4="http://tempuri.org/">
<ns4:newMobile>91----------</ns4:newMobile>
<ns4:countryId>1</ns4:countryId>
<ns4:credentials>
<ns2:Password xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mycompanyWebService.Models">123</ns2:Password>
<ns2:Username xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mycompanyWebService.Models">xyz</ns2:Username></ns4:credentials>
</ns4:myfunction>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Android Client**

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body>
<myfunction xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
<Mobile i:type="d:string">91----------</Mobile>
<countryId i:type="d:string">1</countryId>
<credentials i:type="d:anyType">
<Username i:type="d:string">hm.1</Username>
<Password i:type="d:string">123</Password></credentials>
</myfunction>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

In case of java client it was working but not in android so I used marshaling in order to change the start tag and end tag and it worked for me.